# What are these brown spots on my tomatoes?

Tags: tomatoes

Just formed today. I'm not sure what it could be.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Missouri Botanical Garden has an [informative publication on tomato fruit problems](https://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/gardens-gardening/your-garden/help-for-the-home-gardener/advice-tips-resources/visual-guides/tomato-fruit-problems.aspx). The interesting observation in this case is that the spots all appear in the same rough location on the fruit. If it was a random attack by an insect or splattering by rain or irrigation leaving a local infection the spots would be in different places on the fruit. So there is some event happening like rubbing against a support; this might make sense on one or two fruits but here there are multiple fruits all showing the same thing. Another external event is the rising and setting of the sun which can in some cases lead to sunscald if there was a sudden change such as weather fluctuations or loss of foliage - you would be the best judge whether that is relevant. The document mentions look alike events such as stink bug damage and a bacterial infection but this would be in more random places on the fruit. So that leaves us with the most likely, sunscald. Over to you.